# With Knockout, TAB is not firing change event

Tags: javascript, events, knockout.js

In my view, there is

```
<td><input type="text" data-bind="value:TotalAmount, inputmask: { value:TotalAmount}, event:{change: $root.totalAmountChanged}" /></td>
```

When I TAB out of the input field, the change event does not fire, but if I press ENTER, it does.  Ideally, it should fire on TAB.

So, I added this to my viewmodel:

```
self.changeOnTab = function(obj, event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        $(event.target).change();
    }
```

and changed my view to add the keydown event:

```
<td><input type="text" data-bind="value:TotalAmount, inputmask: { value:TotalAmount}, event:{change: $root.totalAmountChanged, keydown: $root.changeOnTab}" /></td>
```

Now, when I hit TAB, the change event fires, but when I type any numbers into the input field, they are ignored.  It looks like I am missing something in the changeOnTab function that, when keyCode is NOT 9, should preserve my value.

Comment: onchange events do not fire while you are typing in the field. It fires once you leave the field and it sees the value is not the same as when you first entered the field.

Comment: tab keys are a little different. I if you want something to happen with the tab key, you need to catch it with the on key down event handler.

Answer (score 0):

A key reason we have observables is so that you don't have to watch DOM elements, you can watch the observables. Subscribe to `TotalAmount` with whatever you want to do when its value changes.